# Returns only returning single value from list

Tags: python-3.x, automation

I'm trying to return values from list using return but it's only returning single value.
I want to get just numbers (3 tickets) from list of different tickets.
My code is:

```
tickets = find_elements(locator) 
for ticket in tickets:
#Ticket name include full detail like section, row and number of tickets
 txt =ticket.text 
# splitting text eg: "2 tickets" from "2 tickets · e-ticket"
 qty = txt.split()
 return qty[0]
```

It's returning single number.
Please help me solving this and also this this my first question ever posted so pls accept my apologies if guidelines not followed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split with the char but not the space.

```
return txt.split('·')[0].strip()
```

In the above code we are splitting the text using <kbd>·</kbd> and the getting the first part with `[0]`. Finally, `strip()` will remove the leading white spaces.

**Edit 1:**

Here is the approach that you can store the tickets to the list.

```
ticketsList = []
for ticket in tickets:
    #Ticket name include full detail like section, row and number of tickets
     txt =ticket.text 
    # splitting text eg: "2 tickets" from "2 tickets · e-ticket"
     qty = txt.split()
     ticketsList.append(qty[0])
print(ticketsList)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think my question is not clear. I got the required value which is "2" .Using loops I got list like 2 tickets · e-ticket , 3 tickets · e-ticket,4 tickets · e-ticket and I want to return values (2,3,4).

Comment: Do you mean storing all number of tickets in a list? Can you please confirm your locator is returning all those elements, not just the first.

Comment: Yes, locator is returning all values 2 tickets · e-ticket , 3 tickets · e-ticket , 5 tickets · e-ticket .

Comment: Using print it's working fine but when I use return it's jus giving me first value.qty = txt.split()
 print qty[0]

Comment: Got it .. Thanks again.